# Not able to see details stack trace for my IOS app in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am using firebase crashreport for my IOS app to identify the crash report. I tested my app locally in XCode and I was able to see the detailed crash report in Firebase, but since when I generated ipa and uploaded the .dSYM file on Firebase, I am not able to see the detailed crash report. Please refer the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a way to fix it?